# window is not defined in svelte - using svelte store

Tags: javascript, dom, window, svelte, sveltekit

I have a svelte store that has the following code

```
import { writable } from "svelte/store";
import { onMount, onDestroy } from "svelte";

export const modalStore = () => {
    const { subscribe, update } = writable({
        showModal: false,
    });

    onMount(() => {
        window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    });

    onDestroy(() => {
        window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    });

    const handleKeyDown = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
        if (e.key === "Escape") {
            update(stateObj => ({...stateObj, showModal: false}));
        }
    }
    return  {
        subscribe,
        openModal: () => update(stateObj => ({ ...stateObj, modal: true })),
        closeModal: () => update(stateObj => ({ ...stateObj, modal: false })),
        handleKeyDown,

    }
}
```

**Edit**

I have accessed the store by the following code

```
let modalState = modalStore();
```

Then checked the state by **$modalState** and the accessed the function by modalStore.openModal();

It throws 500 error with - window is not defined

How can I solve it?

Comment: The problem has to be SSR. When using svelteKit, every component gets rendered on the server before being sent to the browser. The thing is, `window` is used inside of `onMount` so I think that shouldn't be the problem. Can you share maybe how you are using the store?

Comment: `modalStore` is exported, check whether `openModal` is being called anywhere outside of an `onMount` function?

Comment: @OscarHermoso: I used the openModal function in the component in which the store (modalStore) was called. I have initiated the store by  let modalState = modalStore(); and then accessed modalState.openModal

Comment: Just as you can add event listeners to any DOM element, you can add event listeners to the window object with <svelte:window>. Example: <svelte:window on:keydown={handleKeydown}/>

Comment: @jeff Might be worth making a small demo repo that reproduces the error

Comment: @OscarHermoso Actually I was able to get it working my slightly modifying the onMount function (posted here )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `onDestroy` gets executed on the server. So instead of using `onDestroy` the function returned from `onMount` should be used.

[Docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-ondestroy):

> Out of `onMount`, `beforeUpdate`, `afterUpdate` and `onDestroy`, this is the only one that runs inside a server-side component.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const modalStore = () => {
    const { subscribe, update } = writable({
        showModal: false,
    });

    onMount(() => {
        const handleKeyDown = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
            if (event.key === "Escape") {
                update((storeObj) => {
                    storeObj.showModal = false;
                    return storeObj;
                });
            }
        };

        window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
        };
    });

    const handleKeyDown = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
        if (e.key === "Escape") {
            update(stateObj => ({...stateObj, showModal: false}));
        }
    }


    return  {
        subscribe,
        openModal: () => update(stateObj => ({ ...stateObj, showModal: true })),
        closeModal: () => update(stateObj => ({ ...stateObj, showModal: false })),
        handleKeyDown,
    }
}
```

I dont know how. But its working now without error